# GraphQl Place Order via Stripe

Tags: checkout, graphql, place-order, stripe, magento-graphql

Using Magento 2.4.3 how can i place order via

```
  setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
      cart_id: "FnapbGljNrpKfvYzJ4XxUNxzAchDniY3"
      payment_method: {
          code: "stripe_payments"
      }
  }) {
    cart {
      selected_payment_method {
        code
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can see this is documentation but how do i give card information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fully working example inside the module directory under

```
vendor/stripe/module-payments/examples/GraphQL/PaymentElement/PlaceOrder.html
```